# Cant seem to store HTML input box information in javascript variable

Tags: javascript, html

I am using `getElementByID` to obtain a number put in by a user into an input box, but when i try to display or use said number it comes back as `[object HTMLInputElement]`

```
document.getElementById()
```

is not returning what i would expect.

```
<input type="number" id="first_num">
```

```
var first_number = document.getElementById("first_num").innerHTML = first_num;
console.log(first_number); //  [object HTMLInputElement]
```

http://jsfiddle.net/z9h6jh3f/

Comment: you have to get the value using document.getElementbyId().value

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/z9h6jh3f/1/ were you expecting 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this HTML:

```
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                First Number:<input type="number" id="first_num" value="0">
            </td>
            <td>
                <button type="button" id="calculate_button">Calculate</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

And this Javascript:

```
document.getElementById('calculate_button').addEventListener(
    'click',
    function() {
        var first_num = document.getElementById('first_num').value;
        console.log(first_num); // Or alert(first_num);
    },
    false
);
```

Just to make it clear:

When you use `document.getElementById()` or any other selector like that, you're getting a **DOM object** which has lots of properties and methods, not just its value. Because of that, you have to access the **value** property manually.

Comment: Yeah this makes sense if you're trying to get the value on the click of that button. If that is your intent you definitely need an event listener.

Comment: @MichaelJosephAubry yeah, I tought that because he said he's trying to use the value after the user puts the number in the input... adding the presence of a "Calculate" button, it was pretty obvious :) ... also in the Calculate button, there was a `console.log()` call

Comment: Yeah I agree I was just trying to solve his `it comes back as [object HTMLInputElement]` issue thats what I thought the question was.

Comment: so it was the event listener that made it re-check the contents of the input? also why did you add a false to the function?

Comment: @Plentybinary you want to get the value when the user clicks the Calculate button, that's why I'm capturing the `click` event on that button (adding a **listener** that waits for the `click` event actually). The second parameter is the function that will process that event. The third parameter sets some kind of **priority** to events. It's, according to the W3C, an optional value, but some browsers (like Safari) won't work if you don't define it. Its value is, in the majority of the cases, `false`. There's no need to play with it for your particular purposes (I've never used it anyway).

Comment: Isnt it `return false` I am no expert, I use jQuery more yes I know it's not as cool as going the vanilla way but `return false` comes in handy when you want to avoid the default action for that event that the browser will execute.

Comment: @Plentybinary I think it's great you're using vanilla JS but why not use jQuery?

Comment: Im trying to learn the basics right now, when it comes to actual full projects i will use some kind of framework, but for now i would like to know exactly how it all works so that i have full control over all framework calls. Thanks everybody for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an updated fiddle I assume you're expecting it to return 0.

http://jsfiddle.net/z9h6jh3f/1/

I am not sure why you did `var first_number = document.getElementById("first_num").innerHTML = first_number` but you're just grabbing the value and leaving it at that.

```
var first_number = document.getElementById("first_num").value;
alert(first_number);
```

I also updated the HTML input to start the value at 0.

```
<input type="number" id="first_num" value="0">
```

---

Here is another way you can do it, the way I think you intended.

```
var first_number = 0;
var set_first_number = document.getElementById("first_num").value = first_number;
alert(set_first_number);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/z9h6jh3f/7/

Answer (score 0):

What happens in your code is this:

```
var first_number;
document.getElementById("first_num").innerHTML = first_num;
first_number = first_num; // this is how JS resolves double assignment statements
console.log(first_number);
```

Now, the statement `document.getElementById("first_num").innerHTML = first_num;` does absolutely nothing, because text inputs are always [empty](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-input-element), in the sense that they can have no child nodes. This means that the `innerHTML` setter is a no-op.

But why is `first_num` even defined? You might expect a `first_num is not defined` error. This is a funny thing about ids. Whenever you define an element id, that id [becomes a global variable](http://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/javascript-the-definitive/9781449393854/ch14s07.html) referencing the element itself (unless a variable of that name already exists).

So, for example

```
<div id="foo"></div>
<script>alert(foo) // foo is now the div above</script>
```

In your case, the `first_num` variable is set to the `input` element (and not its value!). In other words, you have

```
first_num === document.getElementById("first_num")
```

Now, let's plug that in your code.

```
var first_number;
document.getElementById("first_num").innerHTML =
    document.getElementById("first_num"); // no-op
first_number = document.getElementById("first_num");
console.log(first_number);
```

You can see now what is happening.

---

What you actually want is

```
var first_number = document.getElementById("first_num").value;
console.log(first_number);
```

And for the button click handler, wrap that in a function

```
function handler() {
    var first_number = document.getElementById("first_num").value;
    console.log(first_number);
}
```

```
<button type="button" onclick="handler();">
```

to make sure the value is updated on each click.

http://jsfiddle.net/z9h6jh3f/8/